# define [browsable] in .NET Portable Subset

Tags: c#, wpf

I want define a property with [Browsable(false)] in .Net Portalbe Subset library. But it can't find Browsalbe define in namespace System.ComponentModel.

Answer (score 1):

The `Portable Library Tools` only support a subset of `.NET`. The `BrowsableAttribute` is simply not supported.

Comment: More suits as Comment

Comment: Why? He is wants to use it and is wondering why he can't find it, and I gave an explanation why. If this is not an answer, then there simply is no answer. `It's not possible` is a perfect valid answer.